# help with modeling phillips head screw

Tags: modeling

I am modeling a phillips head screw. What would be the best way to do this? I need to make the top look realistic. Are there any good textures for this?
My current design:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

Have you considered using the Bolt Factory add-on available from the preferences menu?

There are quite a few options for screws and bolts that you can easily access from the mesh menu once you activate the add-on.

Comment: Does not create phillips head screws. I tried.